# PHP array returning only 1 item

Tags: php, arrays, json, response

I have this part of my code which should return modifier options as an array as shown by the json response below but its only returning 1 item.

```
       {
           "id": "Add-sugar",
           "external_data": "External data for sugar choice",
           "title": {
               "translations": {
                   "en_us": "Add sugar"
               }
           },
           "quantity_info": {
               "quantity": {
                   "max_permitted": 2
               },
               "overrides": []
           },
           "modifier_options": [
               {
                   "id": "Sugar",
                   "type": "ITEM"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": "Add-milk",
           "external_data": "External data for milk choice",
           "title": {
               "translations": {
                   "en_us": "Add milk"
               }
           },
           "quantity_info": {
               "quantity": {
                   "max_permitted": 1
               },
               "overrides": []
           },
           "modifier_options": [
               {
                   "id": "Milk",
                   "type": "ITEM"
               }
           ]
       }
   ],
```

Here is my code below. I want it to return an array of modifier options but I'm only getting array with only one modifier option. May you assist me.

````
                  if($option->field_active[$language][0]['value'] <> 0 && 
                  in_array($uber->field_zone[$language][0]['target_id'], array_column($option->field_zones[$language], 'target_id')) && 
                  in_array("uber_eats", array_column($option->field_viewable[$language], 'value'))){
                    $optionInd['id'] =  $option->id;      
                     $optionInd['external_data'] =  $option->id;
                     $optionInd['title']['translations']['en'] = ucwords(strtolower($option->name));

                         $optionInd['price_info']['price'] = (int)$option->field_pricelevel4[$language][0]['value'];
                    
                     if(isset($option->field_default[$language][0]['value'])){
                     $optionInd['selected_by_default'] = $option->field_default[$language][0]['value'];
                     }
                     if (!in_array($optionInd['id'], array_column($groupInd['modifier_options'], 'id'))){
                     $groupInd['modifier_options'][] = $optionInd;
                     
                     } 
                   } //end if option Active
                 }```

if (!in_array($optionInd['id'], array_column($groupInd['modifier_options'], 'id'))){
                                    $groupInd['modifier_options'][] = array(
                                     "id"=> $optionInd['id'],
                                     "type"=> "ITEM");```

    $modifier[] = $groupInd;
    $menu = array(
    'modifier_groups' => $modifier,
    );
````

Comment: You want all `modifier_options` from all objects in one array?

Comment: Yes I want them all in one array

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help?  ($result below is modifier_options array)

```
$data=json_decode( '{"data":[{"id":"Add-sugar","external_data":"External data for sugar choice","title":{"translations":{"en_us":"Add sugar"}},"quantity_info":{"quantity":{"max_permitted":2},"overrides":[]},"modifier_options":[{"id":"Sugar","type":"ITEM"}]},{"id":"Add-milk","external_data":"External data for milk choice","title":{"translations":{"en_us":"Add milk"}},"quantity_info":{"quantity":{"max_permitted":1},"overrides":[]},"modifier_options":[{"id":"Milk","type":"ITEM"}]}]}',true); # define $data as associative array

$result=[];

foreach ($data['data'] as $a){
    array_push($result, $a['modifier_options']);
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Sugar
                    [type] => ITEM
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Milk
                    [type] => ITEM
                )

        )

)
```